# Print Location of a string

Tags: python

The question itself explain here: `s` is a string to search through and target is the substring to look for. Print each index where the target starts.

```
'''Exercise to complete printLocations as described below.
Create File locations.py.'''

def printLocations(s, target):
    '''
    s is a string to search through, and target is the substring to look for.
    Print each index where the target starts.
    For example:
    >>> printLocations('Here, there, everywherel', 'ere')
    1
    8
    20
    '''

    repetitions = s.count(target)
    # ?? add initialization
    for i in range(repetitions):
        # ?? add loop body lines

def main():
    phrase = 'Here, there, everywhere!'
    print('Phrasez', phrase)
    for target in ['ere', 'er', 'e', 'eh', 'zx']:
        print('finding:', target)
        printLocations(phrase, target)
    print('All done!')

main()
```

Comment: Can you please paste your code here instead of an image?

Comment: So I've edited. And what's wrong? What do you actually want to do?

Comment: Ah...understand after checked your example. So about `'Here, there, everywherel'`, first `ere` is after the 1 letter `H`, and the second one is after `Here, th` and it's 8, another one is at 20. Right?

Comment: @PashNeopane Can you please edit your question to contain the additional information you've added as comments?  SO expects the question to stand on its own, without anyone needing to read the comments.

Comment: You are permitted to ask for help with homework but you are expected to make *some* attempt at writing some relevant code yourself. Don't just dump the assignment description here and expect us to do all the work.

Comment: @kevinguan please do not make edits that disguise the fact that the question is a homework dump.

Comment: @PM2Ring: *Ah...didn't realize that this is a homework question...*

Comment: @kevinguan those `# ??` comments are the clue.

Comment: @PM2Ring: Well, fair enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def printLocations(s, target):
    '''
    s is a string to search through, and target is the substring to look for.
    Print each index where the target starts.
    For example:
    >>> printLocations('Here, there, everywherel', 'ere')
    1
    8
    20
    '''

    repetitions = s.count(target)
    index = -1
    for i in range(repetitions):
        index = s.find(target, index+1)
        print(index)

def main():
    phrase = 'Here, there, everywhere!'
    print('Phrasez', phrase)
    for target in ['ere', 'er', 'e', 'eh', 'zx']:
        print('finding:', target)
        printLocations(phrase, target)
    print('All done!')

main()
```

Demo:

```
Phrasez Here, there, everywhere!
finding: ere
1
8
20
finding: er
1
8
15
20
finding: e
1
3
8
10
13
15
20
22
finding: eh
finding: zx
All done!
```

Comment: @PashNeopane: Edited, check if it's what you want...

Comment: Thanks, I did't mean to copy. I am just learning this language, I read few un-compromise comment by various people. But thanks Kevin. Since I have nothing to do on winter break, I am learning this language. I greatly appreciate it. But can you explain me the reason of initializing index at -1.           thanks

Comment: because you want the first iteration to call `s.find(target, 0)`, and `-1 + 1 == 0`

Answer (score 0):

```
printLocations = lambda s, target: [m.start() for m in re.finditer(re.escape(target), s)]
```

Good luck explaining that to your teacher.... You could also do:

```
printLocation = lambda s, target: [i for i in range(len(s)) if s[i:].startswith(target)]
```